# chrome after post forms ,try to get another captcha image?

Tags: django, python-3.x, captcha, django-formwizard

I'm using the django-simple-captcha in django forms,i used it in a 
subclass of `sessionwizardform`,and in the last wizard form,i put a captcha field in it . 
    at first ,things goes all right ,but after few days ,may be by the duplication of the stale files i installed. in a word ,when i test the wizard form .In the chrome ,the captcha displays pic well,but i fill the right checking words ,in the last post of the form ,it did not post the data,and get another pic for you to validate. 
and i found some answer by my previous question ,but i still can not solve it ,the help url is [`https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/issus/41`](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/issues/41) ,and my previous question url is [`django-simple-captcha-keeps-saying-invalid-captcha`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853114/django-simple-captcha-keeps-saying-invalid-captcha) .
in it ,i described the detail of my `django-simple-captcha`.
likewise ,i'm still not know much about the `globally` and the `virturenv`, I have the `django-simple-captcha` uninstalled and reinstalled ,have the `django` uninstalled and reinstalled ,
...
but none of these worked ,and i do not  re-defined the `CAPTCHA_OUTPUT_FORMAT`in my settings.in the chrome ,i tested like 
this

```
 <td width="70%" class="text-left">
 <img src="/captcha/image/d61b817a32d5aee07a4c2f8ce3cf71ccc7dea85f/" alt="captcha" class="captcha"> 
 <input class="form-control" id="id_xy_assist-captcha_0" name="xy_assist-captcha_0" type="hidden" value="d61b817a32d5aee07a4c2f8ce3cf71ccc7dea85f"> 
 <input class="form-control" id="id_xy_assist-captcha_1" name="xy_assist-captcha_1" type="text">
 </td>
```

and i think this is allright,but in the chrome after all the fields 
post ,there is another get captcha image which make this wizard form data can never be saved.and without this captcha field ,everything is right .
and comparing with the [issues/41](https://github.com/mbi/django-simple-captcha/issues/41) in the url.
my test of captcha has two `Internal Server Error`,one for `/test/`,one for `/test-modelform/`.
and there is not any captcha directory except this one ?
could any one help me find a way to solve it ?
i am usint python 3.3 ,and i'd like django-simple-captcha reserved,which is really simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours checking codes and testing ,i found my programming is very poor ,i canot resolve this question ,and since i 'm a newby.
nearly tried all ways ,i solved it by this :
i copy [`his code`](https://code.google.com/p/django-simple-captcha/issues/detail?id=4#c6) to the newest django-simple-captcha's fields.py and reserves the class`class BaseCaptchaTextInput`,
but the test in the captcha is not passed ,and i ignore it.
and i think my `python's class` has not well understand , and have to spend time on it to improve myself.